# css3 animation: seamless screen movement

Tags: css-transitions

getting a little stick with something, i have a site where i have water at the bottom and i wanted it to move from left to right constantly, giving it the illusion of seamlessly flowing water, something similar to whats on this site, except not a hover state and only horizontal.

http://www.priteshgupta.com/2011/07/filling-a-glass-with-water-using-html5/

the html i have is a simple empty div tag (everything is on the css)

```
<div id="water"></div>
```

and the css is:

```
#water {
  background: url(img/ocean.png);   
  margin-top: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: water 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes water {
  to {transform: translate(100px,0);}
  from {transform: translate(0px,0);}
}
```

image looks like this: http://prntscr.com/1hwfnz

any ideas on the best way to do this?
any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

as a side note i tried this css:

```
#water {
  background: url(img/ocean.png);   
  margin-top: 1000px;
  width: 200%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: water 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes water {
to {transform: translate(100px,0);}
from {transform: translate(0px,0);}
}
```

i could set the overflow to hide x and that should deal with the scrolling issue and allow the water to flow, the problem being that when the water cycle finishes there is an ugly jump cut back to the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the transition to only `water`, then you can see exactly what your animation actually does - just moves the whole image right 100px, jumps back to original position, then does it again

What you need to have is something like

```
#water {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Lrvw1oc.png);   
  /*margin-top: 1000px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: water 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: water 3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: water 3s ease-out;
  transition: water 3s ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: water 2000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes water {  
  0% {background-position: 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: 100000% 0;}
}
```

Which moves the background position, not the whole image.

[Here is a demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/backgroundanimation)

**Note**: the 2000s and 100,000% are a work around to prevent that 'ugly jump cut' from happening. It's possible that my implementation could be slightly wrong